# Website's header not in position on Internet Explorer

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've made a website with Wordpress, everything's fine except on Internet Explorer 11. The header's li and ul go down, I suspect an incompatible CSS rule in the theme I used. I already had to correct somethings that weren't responsive as advertised, and I reach the end of my knowledge.

Most parts of the header are in position:relative. I played with the padding also, it went up a little but not at it's initial place.

Fun fact, when the wordpress admin bar is visible, the header gets (sometimes) back to normal.

The URL of the website : https://cdj-vaud.ch

The support team gave this CSS fix, but it works only on Chrome and Firefox.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
  .edgtf-main-menu ul li a {
    font-size: 12px !important;
  }
.edgtf-main-menu>ul>li>a span.edgtf-item-inner {
  padding: 0 5px;
  }
}
```

If someone knows what rule isn't recognized by Internet Explorer, it would be awesome !

Answer (score 0):

in chrome on mac os x its broken too.
 just play around with the margin left and right. that fixed it for me.

```
.edgtf-vertical-align-containers 
.edgtf-position-center:before, 
.edgtf-vertical-align-containers 
.edgtf-position-left:before, 
.edgtf-vertical-align-containers 
.edgtf-position-right:before {
    margin-right: -25px;
}
```

Comment: Well, it worked pretty well ! Just had to compensate the margin on firefox because the logo was resized.Thank you very much it helped me a lot !

The icons still don't appear, it's not the biggest problem though, if I can't show them on IE I'll delete them.